# What will happen if the given offset in fseek goes beyond the last character

Tags: c++

I'm currently using c++ and trying to write a file using fseek() in order to write on the given offset calculated from other methods. Just wondering what will happen if the given offset will make the FILE pointer go beyond the last character in the file.

Example:
In a file with "abcdefg" as the contents, what will fseek(someFILEpointer, 20, SEEK_SET) return?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fseek):

> POSIX allows seeking beyond the existing end of file. If an output is performed after this seek, any read from the gap will return zero bytes. Where supported by the filesystem, this creates a sparse file.

It sounds like it should return a non-error status, but subsequent reads may fail.  Subsequent writes may succeed, but the exact behavior may depend on the underlying filesystem.

Comment: In other words, undefined behaviour. It may cause your computer to grow legs and join an outlaw biker gang.

Comment: @user4581301 -- well, not really.  It sounds like it's defined and somewhat implementation-dependent.

Comment: Going to go a bit pedantic on you here, and this has nothing to do with the quality of your answer. This is more a breadcrumb for future readers: In C++, and every other language I've worked with, if the outcome of an operation is not stated in the language standard, you have undefined behaviour. Sometimes the outcome is poorly worded and open to interpretation, but it is either defined or it isn't and future revisions of the standard will clean up the wording.

Comment: I'm aware of what 'undefined behavior' means.  My point was that the C++ standard, like many other standards, makes a distinction between UB and implementation-defined behavior.  This particular edge case appears to be an instance of the latter.

Comment: There is nothing undefined nor unspecified here, though. If you have a Posix system and you are applying `fseek` to a regular file, then you can fseek beyond the end of the file and write, and any skipped bytes will subsequently be read as zero. The only unspecified part is whether the filesystem optimizes the storage of the zeroes; Posix merely guarantees that the file will act as though it had zeroes stored in the "gap". The C standard, on the other hand, leaves it as implementation-defined whether you can even do an fseek with an offset to SEEK_END.

Answer (score 2):

The C standard leaves it implementation-defined whether such a call to `fseek` succeeds or not. If the file position cannot be set in the manner indicated, `fseek` will return an error indication.

From the C standard:

> A binary stream need not meaningfully support `fseek` calls with a whence value of `SEEK_END`. (§7.21.9.2/3)
>
> For a text stream, either offset shall be zero, or offset shall be a value returned by an earlier successful call to the `ftell` function on a stream associated with the same file and whence shall be `SEEK_SET`.

So in neither case are you guaranteed to be able to call `fseek` with a non-zero offset and whence set to `SEEK_END`.

Posix does allow the call (quotes from the [description of `fseek`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fseek.html)):

> The `fseek()` function shall allow the file-position indicator to be set beyond the end of existing data in the file. If data is later written at this point, subsequent reads of data in the gap shall return bytes with the value 0 until data is actually written into the gap.

(Posix leaves it up to the implementation whether the bytes with value 0 are actually stored, or are implicit. Most Unix file systems implement sparse files which can optimize this case by not storing the zeros on persistent storage, but this is not possible on a FAT filesystem, for example.)

Even Posix only makes this guarantee for regular files:

> The behavior of `fseek()` on devices which are incapable of seeking is implementation-defined. The value of the file offset associated with such a device is undefined.

So the call may fail, but that is not undefined behaviour. If the repositioning is not possible, `fseek` will return a nonzero value; in the case of Posix implementations, the nonzero value will be `-1` and `errno` will be set to a value which might help clarify the cause of the failure.

Answer (score 1):

In linux (and unix in general), it would succed and return the new offset measured from the beginning of the file, but the file won't increase in size until you write something at that offset.

Your unwritten part will be read back as zeros from the file, but depending on OS and file system, some of the zeros might not have to occupy space on the harddrive.